# Javascript - Slow onMouseOver and onMouseOut

Tags: javascript, html, css, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have two events on div. onMouseOver and onMouseOut.
Events changing visibility of another divs.

But there is a delay on first load, maybe 1 sec.

Script in head

```
<script>
    function onTulipanOver() {
        document.getElementById("tulipan-left").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("tulipan-pozadi").style.visibility = "visible";
    } 
    function onTulipanOut() {
        document.getElementById("tulipan-left").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("tulipan-pozadi").style.visibility = "hidden";
    } 
</script>
```

Part of body

```
<div class="section group">
    <div class="section group radek1sloupec blok_velky " >
        <div class=" radek2sloupece obrazek_levo tulipan-left" id="tulipan-left"></div>
        <div class=" radek2sloupece obrazek_stred tulipan-right" onMouseOver="onTulipanOver()" onMouseOut="onTulipanOut()"></div>
        <div class="radek2sloupece popis tulipan-pozadi" id="tulipan-pozadi">
            <span>The Red<br/>Tulip</span> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there some solution how I can fix it?

Comment: _But there is a delay on first load_ what _first load_ ?

Comment: What are you putting in the div? Images will not load instantaneously as they need to download/stream for display.

Comment: In div is image. Can I download this image when I loading page?

Comment: Unclear how the image is displayed in the div. I’m assuming it’s CSS background image so you may try some CSS preloading techniques like this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-only-image-preloading/